# @TestConfiguration and @Configuration Spring annotations load the exact same context and should

Tags: spring, testing, annotations, spring-context

i try to understand why using @TestConfiguration instead of @Configuration.
According to documentations on the net, i can read that with
@TestConfiguration, all the spring context is not loaded, and so application could be more quick to load context.

But what does it mean.
Could someone give an expample of the added value of @TestConfiguration.